# How do I edit code on PythonanyWhere console?

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python, and tried downloading Python on my computer but had some issues because I have a very old Macbook that can only run OSX 10.6. I have been trying to use Python Anywhere, but I cant seem to edit the code I write in the console. For example, if I write a bunch of code and then run it and get an parentheses error, I have to re-enter all of that code onto the next command line and add the parentheses rather than just adding the parentheses to the code and re-running it. I can just copy and paste the bad code onto the new line, fix the error, and then re-run the code, but this gets tedious. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have used R a bit before and in R you can simply edit the code, then run it again, so I am wondering if there is a way to write Python code in this same manner.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you can't find an editor? Learn how to use vim, emacs, etc.

Comment: Basically I just want to know if there is a way to fix code with an error other than rewriting all of the code on anew command line

Comment: You know that OS X comes with Python 2.7 installed, right?

Answer (score 2):

There's two main ways of entering code into PythonAnywhere:

- the first is to type it interactively into a live interpreter or "Console".  You do that from the PythonAnywhere "Consoles" tab.  it sounds like that's what you've done so far
- the second is to create a file.  You do that via the "Files" tab.  if you create a new file with a .py ending (eg hello.py) PythonAnywhere will bring up an editor which you can use to save a file, and then you can run it, see the output below the editor, then make changes, re-run, etc.

[image: screenshot of pythonanywhere editor]

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use vim editor on the console file edit

use: vim <file_name>
[image]